# Problem with updating data in database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, crud

I have a form that has username, job, date of birth and city inputs. I am trying to update them through my form. When I click submit button my form submits but data remains unchanged. I successfully read them from database but when I try and update nothing happens. Any help is appreciated. Here is my code.

UserController.php

```
public function showProfile($username, Request $request)
{
    $profileId = User::getIdFromUsername($username);

    $userForShowProfile = User::with('userProfile')->where('id', $profileId)->first();

    return view('profile.show', compact('userForShowProfile'));
}

public function updatePersonalData(UpdatePersonalDataRequest $request)
{
    $user = Auth::user();

    $request->validated();

    $user->where('id', $user->id)->update(
        [
            'username' => $request->username,
            'job' => $request->job,
            'date_of_birth' => $request->date_of_birth,
            'updated_at' =>  Carbon::now()
        ]
    );

    $city = City::where('name', $request['city'])->first();

    if ($city != null && $city->count() > 0) {
        $request->user()->city()->associate($city->id);
    }

    $request->user()->save();

    return response()->json(null, 204);
}
```

web.php

```
Route::get('profile/{profile}', 'UserController@showProfile')->name('profile.show');
Route::patch('profile/personal', 'UserController@updatePersonalData')->name('profile.update.personal.data');
```

show.blade.php

```
<section data-edit="generalInfo" class="editGeneralInfo">
    <form action="{{ route('profile.update.personal.data') }}" method="POST" class="flex">
        @method('PATCH')
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="textBold">Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="{{ $userForShowProfile->username }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="textBold">Ort</label>
        <input type="text" name="job" value="{{ $userForShowProfile->job }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="textBold">Beruf</label>
            <input type="text" name="city" value="{{ $userForShowProfile->city->name }}">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-0">
            <label for="" class="textBold">Geburtsdatum</label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" name="date_of_birth" value="{{ $userForShowProfile->date_of_birth }}">
            <p class="infoText mt-2">Dein Geburtsdatum wird nicht öffentlich angezeigt.</p>
            <p class="infoText">Wir ermitteln damit nur dein Alter</p>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
            <label for="" class="textBold">Button</label>
            <input type="submit" class="form-control" name="submit" value="BUTTON">
        </div>
    </form>
</section>
```

rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username' => ['string', 'max:255', 'unique:users,username'],
        'job' => ['string', 'max:255'],
        'date_of_birth' => ['date', 'date_format:d.m.Y'],
        'city' => ['string', 'max:255', 'exists:cities,name']
    ];
}
```

Comment: `$user->where('id', $user->id)` seems very redundant, given that `$user` is the `$user`?

Comment: ok, I will fix that, but do you know where is the actual problem?

Comment: your `if` statements in `updatePersonalData` function returns `true`?

Comment: when I try to dd() anywhere in that function and click on submit button dd() doesn't work.

Comment: I'm guessing that your validation rules fails, because there is no exception to the username to that user ID.

Comment: Also the `city` field may not be present, if the check for it fails? The check could also be simplified to `if ($city) {`, since it will be falsy value if there was no match.

Comment: @Qirel Yeah you are right my validation breaks. When I comment it out update works fine. Can you help me how to write proper validation for username and city?

Comment: You probably just need to update the username to ignore the current ID, something like `'unique:users,username,'.$this->user->id`

Comment: @Qirel Ok. And that's it? I don't need to pass that user id anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

I have a same problem in my code the error is:

I save like this : `$user->save();`

While i change the data using: `$user` and `$user->profile`

So i added in my code another line: `$user->profile->save()`

It work now